# how to prevent duplicated mail without deleting mails on server

Tags: linux, mutt, email

I run getmail + maildrop to get all mails locally, but every time getmail runs, it will download a copy of all messages. 
even setting delete option in getmail or mailfilter config does not help

the related config:

[options]
verbose = 5
read_all = 0
delete = 0

`/usr/bin/reformail  -D 8000 $HOME/.getmail/duplicate.cache`
if ( $RETURNCODE == 0 )
 exit